# When adding lazy column inside another lazy column in android jetpack compose it shows error

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

How to add a lazy column inside another lazy column in jetpack compose like below screenshot.(The inner list size maybe vary)

[image]

```
@Composable
fun SingleItem() {

LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
          ),
         
        ) {
    
            item {
    
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
    
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_school),
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
    
                    Text(
                        text = "School",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .weight(1f)
                     
                    )
    
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_down_arrow),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_large))
                            .clip(CircleShape)
                            .clickable { isExpand = !isExpand },
                        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.expand_list)
                    )
    
                }
    
            }
    
            if (isExpand) {
    
                item {
                    Divider(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(vertical = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_large))
                            .background(DividerColor.copy(alpha = 0.5F))
                            .fillMaxWidth(), thickness = 0.5.dp
                    )
                }
    
    
                items(3) {
                    Row(modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_large))
                        .fillMaxWidth()) {
    
                        Text("School",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .weight(1f),
                           
                        )
    
                        Text(text = "3 KM",
                            textAlign = TextAlign.End
                         
                        )
    
                    }
                }
            }
    
        }

}
```

//For Full list

```
@Composable
fun MainList()
{
    LazyColumn() {

        items(10) {
            SingleItem()
        }
    }
}
```

But using this code it shows following error.

Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()). If you want to add a header before the list of items please add a header as a separate item() before the main items() inside the LazyColumn scope. There are could be other reasons for this to happen: your ComposeView was added into a LinearLayout with some weight, you applied Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true) or wrote a custom layout. Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the hierarchy above the scrolling container.

Comment: @nglauber .....

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to avoid Nested Scrolling in the same direction. One possible hack if you already know the size of the component you can use that in modifier.
or try wrapping all of your composables inside one parent LazyColumn and using its DSL to pass in different types of content.

In your example

```
@Composable
fun MainList()
{
    LazyColumn() {

        items(10) { item ->
            ListComposable(item)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ListComposable(item: List<String>){
//...
}
```

This item can also be a multiple list item.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#avoid-nesting-scrollable

Comment: don't know the size of second lazycolumn item. It maybe vary. Maybe from 0 to 50 in each item.

Comment: you can check  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ANt65eoNhQ&t=899s youtube video about the topic as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992694/how-to-create-expandable-list-view-with-static-values-in-jetpack-compose/68995732#68995732 answer for a basic example - shortly you can place your content in a separate item/items. Also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71709816/3585796 answer may be useful for building a dynamic items tree.