# How to achieve multiple header and body elements list for a LazyColumn in compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to achieve the following layout [image]

All the headers like Claim requested credentials, Claim received credentials, Pending requests etc are dynamic and will be coming from backend and the items for each header like Module 1:... etc are dynamic as well.  Also I need the `card` to encapsulate both Header and the Body item.

Here is what I have tried

```
LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset(x = 0.dp, y = 110.dp)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 20.dp, topEnd = 20.dp),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant
            )
            .padding(12.dp)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(
            listOf(
                "Claim requested credentials",
                "Claim received credentials",
                "Pending Requests"
            )
        ) { index, item ->
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .statusBarsPadding()
                    .background(
                        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
                    )
                ,elevation = 20.dp,
                contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant,
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant
            ) {
                Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 12.dp)) {
                    ManageCredentialHeader(text = item, vcsNo = 2)
                    LazyColumn(){
                        itemsIndexed(listOf(1,2,3)){ index, item ->
                            ManageCredentialItem()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I get an error saying  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()). If you want to add a header before the list of items please add a header as a separate item() before the main items() inside the LazyColumn scope. There are could be other reasons for this to happen: your ComposeView was added into a LinearLayout with some weight, you applied Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true) or wrote a custom layout. Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the hierarchy above the scrolling container.`

How to achieve this kind of dynamic layout with LazyColumn in compose. In `react-native` this was easily achieved using `SectionList`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Jetpack Compose when you create layouts like LazyColumn or any other layout you measure your Composables as `Measurables` with the limits coming from Constraints as min/max width/height. Modifier.scroll or LazyList returns max as Constraints.Infinity which is not permitted for child LazyColumn. That's why you get that exception.

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73316247/5457853) i explained which modifier returns which Constraints. You can check out Constraints section.

Since you don't have a height for the Column add a size modifier that changes maxHeight of inner LazyColumn from Constraints.Infinity to something finite such as

```
   Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 12.dp)
                        .heightIn(max = 500.dp) {


}
```

max height is not the fixed value set, it's the biggest height that child LazyColumns can get. You can change it as required. Your items can grow in height up to this.

Implementation

```
@Composable
private fun LazyListSample() {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 20.dp, topEnd = 20.dp),
                color = Color(0xffE3F2FD)
            )
            .padding(12.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 10.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {

        itemsIndexed(
            listOf(
                "Claim requested credentials",
                "Claim received credentials",
                "Pending Requests"
            )
        ) { index, item ->
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .statusBarsPadding(),
                elevation = 20.dp,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),

                ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 12.dp)
                        .heightIn(max = 500.dp)
                ) {
                    ManageCredentialHeader(text = item, vcsNo = 2)
                    LazyColumn(
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
                    ) {
                        itemsIndexed(listOf(1, 2, 3)) { index, item ->
                            ManageCredentialItem()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ManageCredentialHeader(text: String, vcsNo: Int) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(text)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
        Box( modifier = Modifier
            .size(24.dp)
            .background(Color.Blue,CircleShape)
            .padding(2.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                vcsNo.toString(),
                color = Color.White
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

    }
}

@Composable
private fun ManageCredentialItem() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp)) {
        Column() {
            Text("Module 1 some text")
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
                Text("Subtitle")
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Text(
            "VIEW",
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xff283593), RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .padding(6.dp),
            color = Color.White
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: it's not going to work for pagination lists, it's only for fixed size list

Comment: This breaks for cards taller than 500.dp doesn't it? I would just use a normal Column inside the card in this case instead (if it's expected there are not too many items on each body)

Comment: Yes, if cards are taller than 500.dp it limits maximum height to 500.dp but it's some arbitrary number, what you need to do with inner scrolalble Composable or LazyColumn is to not measure its height with Constraints.Infinity. To do that you set a maximum measurement bound for height  that is finite bound. They simply added a Constraints.Infinity check for inner Composable to not let it scroll forever.

Comment: This code is especially useful when you don't know the height of grid, LazyColumn to not limit them smaller then they should be and of let them to be measured between 0 and some finite number since their content is not infinite. Or when you have inner LazyColumn that you wish to scroll items, so you limit height and they become scrollable

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you need a single dynamic `LazyColumn` here.

You don't have to only use `items` at the topmost level - if you check out its source code, you'll see that it's just adds single `item` in a loop.

You can build your lazy content by adding multiple items inside an other loop, something like this:

```
LazyColumn {
    listOf(
        "Claim requested credentials",
        "Claim received credentials",
        "Pending Requests"
    ).forEach { header ->
        item(
            contentType = "header"
        ) {
            Text(header)
        }
        items(
            count = 10,
            contentType = "body",
        ) { bodyIndex ->
            Text(bodyIndex.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem there

> ```kotlin
>                     LazyColumn(){
>                         itemsIndexed(listOf(1,2,3)){ index, item ->
>                             ManageCredentialItem()
>                         }
>                     }
> ```

You cannot nest LasyColumn inside LazyColumn, but you can replace it like this:

```kotlin
Column {
    for (index, item in listOf(1, 2, 3).withIndex()) {
        ManageCredentialItem()
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't make it Lazy

Comment: I have found related question, maybe comments under answer from there will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73609560/when-adding-lazy-column-inside-another-lazy-column-in-android-jetpack-compose-it